# Develop remotely in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

Anyone can explain to me how to do remote development using Visual Studio? What I want to achieve is:

- When I click create new project on visual studio, it should create the project files and solution and reference and all dependencies on the remote server instead of my local machine.
- When I save files. it actually update the remote files.
- When I build the project, it actually build/compile the files on the remote server.
- I don't want local copy of the files. I want all the files resides on the server.

I know it may sound trivia for some people. But I'm new to this .NET things and I've spend two hours to get this working with no success. I found MSDN article on how to open (via FTP) remote file that already there, but i can't find article that mention how to create new project on remote server.

Background story why am I want to do this: I'm new at my office, and no folks here familiar with version control like git or TFS. They do all development (code and backup on the dev server) using notepad++ and FTP (they are using classic VBScript for code). I'm not familiar with VBScript but quite familiar with C#. That's why i need the compiler. The reason why it must be built on the server is because somehow, for some reason, some remote DB's cannot be accessed from local machine so I cannot test my app from the local, but if it run on the server, it doin just fine.

Comment: How about installing Visual Studio on the remote server and using Remote Desktop or something to login and work directly on it? Is that a feasible option?

Comment: Could you describe why cuz it could help to craft it

Comment: @ Drew Pierce I update my question :)

Comment: @shree.pat18 It feasible, but not so comfortable to do. You know, the server is old (win 2003), it doesnt support VS 2013 i'm using in my local PC which is pretty slick, and ultimately I think it will slow the server for other developers.

Comment: I can't imagine there's a way to do this. Sounds like it's your job to modernize their processes, or give up on them and get a job with a real company.

Comment: @John Saunders That is exactly what I'm doing now. I talk to the team to use version control. but you know, I'm a junior here, and the tasks must be done. lol.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe remind them that Visual Studio Online is free for teams of up to 5, and includes source control, work item tracking and automated builds. That should bring them right into the 90's.